# Spring MockWebServiceServer handling multiple async requests

Tags: java, spring, soap, integration-testing

I have multiple async soap requests and I need to mock the responses of those requests. However, it seems the order of the expected requests matter and I was wondering if there were any workarounds.

I came across [this example using MockRestServiceServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793385/spring-mockrestserviceserver-handling-multiple-async-requests) where it uses the ignoreExpectOrder() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own implementation of the ResponseCreator that sets up a number of URI and responses (for asynchronous requests) and return the matching response based on the input URI. I've done something similar and it is works.

Comment: Can you provide sample code of how you implemented it?